# Any way to prevent computer from rebooting

Tags: linux, debian, boot, reboot

I am trying to create an environment on my computer where it simply never receives updates or it might receive updates but still never reboot on its own.

My question is can I achieve this on any Linux distro? If so can someone direct me towards how to do this? I have heard of UNIX servers running indefinitely so I am just assuming this is achievable with Linux as well. If not it would be nice to clear up the confusion. Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Debian based systems, like Ubuntu, the package responsible for automatic updates is called `unattended-upgrades`.

If you want to stop automatic security updates to the system, a simple way is to uninstall it, as in:

```
sudo apt remove unattended-upgrades
```

From `man unattended-upgrade'

> unattended-upgrade - automatic installation of security (and other)
>   upgrades
>
> This  program  can  download  and  install security upgrades
>   automatically and unattended,
>          taking care to only install packages from the configured APT source, and checking for dpkg
>          prompts  about  configuration  file  changes. All output is logged to /var/log/unattended-
>          upgrades.log.
>
> ```
>    This script is the backend for the APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade option  and  designed
>    to be run from cron (e.g. via /etc/cron.daily/apt).
> ```

As for rebooting, it is not mandatory rebooting after upgrades. You can keep using it. However if you want to keep running it over time, the system is generally more happy if you do not delete the packages of the version of the kernel that is running.

Obviously from the point of view of security, it is advised to update packages, and reboot periodically when there is a new kernel update to be running a new kernel version.

You also have some Linux versions were the kernel is patched on run-time, and you rarely need to reboot.

Comment: If the user means "services" rather than "servers", then one could have a redundant/failover system take over the services of the first system during the time of reboot.